# What is the Difference Between 1Ghz Mobile Processor and 1Gzh Pc pocessor?

Tags: 64-bit, arm, x86

What is the difference between a 1Ghz ARM mobile processor and a 1Ghz x86 processor?. I mean both are 1Ghz right. Then how is it differs in performance other than the architecture?. why if we compile one-same application for 2 architecture it gives 2 different outputs (performance).

Comment: Just a sidenote, as you are comparing ARM with x86 processors here which is a big difference. An Intel 10th generation I5 running 3Ghz vs an Intel 6th generation I5 running 3Ghz will already be a huge difference in speed, due to the architecture of the processor. Clock Speed is not saying much anymore.

Comment: Ghz just tells you how many times a circuit flips between working states. It tells you nothing about the amount of real work achieved between every state change.